# Why does the addition of enclosing parentheses change the result of this Scala expression?

Tags: scala

I'm porting some C code to Scala, which makes extensive use of floating point arithmetic.  I wrote the following code in Scala based on a copy/paste of the C version:

```
val complimentaryTerms = 2640.96e-6 * sin (f5)
          +  63.52e-6 * sin (2.0 * f5)
          +  11.75e-6 * sin (2.0 * f3 - 2.0 * f4 + 3.0 * f5)
          +  11.21e-6 * sin (2.0 * f3 - 2.0 * f4 +       f5)
          -  4.55e-6 * sin (2.0 * f3 - 2.0 * f4 + 2.0 * f5)
          +  2.02e-6 * sin (2.0 * f3            + 3.0 * f5)
          +  1.98e-6 * sin (2.0 * f3            +       f5)
          -  1.72e-6 * sin (3.0 * f5)
          -  0.87e-6 * t * sin (f5)
```

The result of this computation is slightly off from what the C version produces.  However, if I enclose the expression in parentheses, like this:

```
val complimentaryTerms = (2640.96e-6 * sin (f5)
          +  63.52e-6 * sin (2.0 * f5)
          +  11.75e-6 * sin (2.0 * f3 - 2.0 * f4 + 3.0 * f5)
          +  11.21e-6 * sin (2.0 * f3 - 2.0 * f4 +       f5)
          -  4.55e-6 * sin (2.0 * f3 - 2.0 * f4 + 2.0 * f5)
          +  2.02e-6 * sin (2.0 * f3            + 3.0 * f5)
          +  1.98e-6 * sin (2.0 * f3            +       f5)
          -  1.72e-6 * sin (3.0 * f5)
          -  0.87e-6 * t * sin (f5))
```

the resulting value matches exactly the C version.  It seems the order of operations must be different when there are enclosing parentheses vs when there are not, but I don't understand why that would make any difference.  Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Weird.  A bug?  Why don't you try gradually simplifying the expression until you get the simplest expression that gives a discrepancy?  eg does `2640.96e-6 * sin (f5) +  63.52e-6 * sin (2.0 * f5)` give a discrepancy?  What if you remove the coefficient of the first term?

Comment: (You could also try looking at the emitted bytecode.  It's not as scary as it sounds.  It's not like looking at x86 assembler (though admittedly it's not far off).  Try to get a simple expression first though, so the bytecode is relatively short.  I suspect it's something to do with the inferred type of complimentaryTerms.

Comment: (Hmmm, you could also try `println complimentaryTerms.getClass()`, and see if it's the same or not.

Comment: Try moving the + and - to the preceding line, so that they are at the end of the line rather than the beginning.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because of semicolon inference. Sample (`//;` - inferred semicolon):

```
val x = 1 //;
        + 1 //;
println(x) // 1
```

And with parentheses:

```
val x = (1
        + 1) //;
println(x) // 2
```

Or with tailing "+":

```
val x = 1 +
        1 //;
println(x) // 2
```

> **The rules of semicolon inference**
>   A line ending is treated as a semicolon unless one of the following conditions is true:
>
> 1. The line in question ends in a word that would not be legal as the end of a statement, such as a period or an infix operator.
> 2. The next line begins with a word that cannot start a statement.
> 3. The line ends while inside parentheses (...) or brackets [...], because these cannot contain multiple statements anyway.

Comment: Well spotted.   And the rule sounds so reasonable.  And yet.... this bug is totally non-obvious.  I suppose it becomes obvious the second time you come across this bug?

Comment: It also doesn't error because there are `unary_+` and `unary_-` methods, i.e. the fact that `+ 1.1` is a valid expression but (for example) `* 1.1` isn't.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention about it.

Comment: That's quite a gotcha.  I'm surprised I've not heard about it before.  I seem to recall a brief mention of this issue in the Odersky book but it obviously didn't make an impression.